# What exactly is URL-safe Base 64 encoding?

Tags: appsec, encoding

And how is it different form the normal Base 64 encoding?

Comment: It doesn’t use "/". You can just look that up on the Wikipedia page of base encoding.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table